# Custom ListView Subitem checkbox [Hashmap <String,boolean>]

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, simpleadapter

Link : [ListView](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html#comment-form) [MyExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRhQx.jpg)

So I followed the tutorial link above to add subitem using :

> `static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();`

to add String for subitem.

Now, I wanted to add a boolean checkbox to the existing String, I use

> `static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,Boolean>> DAMN=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Boolean>>();`

Example of my private void listViewItem():

```
    private void listViewItem(){
    HashMap<String,String> hash=new HashMap<String, String>();
    hash.put("Student_name","Joshua");
    hash.put("Student_ID","111111464");
    list.add(hash);
    HashMap<String,Boolean>boo=new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    boo.put("attend",true);
    DAMN.add(boo);'
```

On my onCreate, I include both SimpleAdapter for adapter ( String,String) and (String, Boolean)

> `SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(
>                   this,OMG,R.layout.tolist_row,
>                   new String[]{"Student_name","Student_ID"},
>                   new int[] {R.id.StudenName,R.id.studentID});
>   SimpleAdapter adapter1=new SimpleAdapter(this,DAMN,R.layout.tolist_row1,
>                   new String[] {"attend"},
>                   new int[] {R.id.attend});`

```
    listViewItem();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    setListAdapter(adapter1);
```

The problem I can only get is my checkbox checked or unchecked but not the ID and name. 
Unless I comment
`//setListAdapter(adapter1)` only I can get my Student_name and Student_name but without the checkbox ticked.
How do I have both result ?

Comment: You need a custom adapter and custom logic to handle that. Create your own list adapter and in its getView method do what you need based on your logic. Check out google for examples of having a custom list adapter.

Comment: How do I combine my 'Hashmap for <String,String>' and 'Hashmap <String,Boolean>' for my checkbox together ? Is it possible ? @ Nazgul

Comment: Yes it is if you use a custom Adapter. Normal adapter have only one data source usually a List or a Map. You can have both HashMaps in your adapter and presuming you use same keys for both you can extract Boolean and String values from them in the getView method of your custom adapter.

Comment: Am I closed to it ? What more do I need to add in my code ? I cant get it, can you help me with simple code ? Thanks @Nazgul

Answer (score -1):

I cannot give you the whole code but for a start, do something like this:

First create DataHolder for your data i.e: Strings and Booeleans etc. idea if to use a composite custom object as data holder instead of raw Strings and booleans.

```
public class DataHolder{
    private String studentNname;
    private Boolean attended;

    //add getters and setters etc.

}
```

Now implement your adapter like this.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    //populate this data using constructor or a setter or any other way
    private List<DataHolder> data;

    private LayoutInflater inflater = ....
    //get the inflater form the fragment or the activity which ever you are using;


    //implement overridden and abstract methods
    //for counts of items return the size of HashMap

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your list item layout xml file>, null);
        }
        DataHolder dataHolder = this.getItem(position);
        //now you have the convertView (your list item view) 
        //and the data to be show in that view (dataHolder object)
        //populate the convertView with the data from the dataHolder

        return convertView;
    } 

}
```

Finally create an instance of this adapter, provide it the data i.e: List and pass this instance to setAdapter of listView.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to say why the -1 here? The approach is a very scalable and practical approach suggested.